# Some Questions about the tensorflow keras layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a freshman in NLP. I encountered some problems when I was going through someone's code in github. So the code is about NL2SQL.The author processed dataset like this.

```
Output token_ids:
[101, 753, 7439, 671, 736, 2399, 5018, 1724, 1453, 1920, 7942, 6044, 1469, 2166, 2147, 6845, 4495, 6821, 697, 6956, 2512, 4275, 4638, 4873, 2791, 2600, 1304, 3683, 3221, 1914, 2208, 1435, 102, 11, 2512, 4275, 1399, 4917, 102, 12, 1453, 4873, 2791, 102, 12, 4873, 2791, 1304, 3683, 102, 12, 1767, 1772, 782, 3613, 102]
Output segment_ids:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output header_ids:
[33 39 44 50]
```

He added the columns after the questions. Then sent the whole sentences into bert to be encoded. And after processing, the input dataset looks like this. There is an example of batch size of 2.

```
nput_token_ids : shape(2, 57)
[[ 101  753 7439  671  736 2399 5018 1724 1453 1920 7942 6044 1469 2166
  2147 6845 4495 6821  697 6956 2512 4275 4638 4873 2791 2600 1304 3683
  3221 1914 2208 1435  102   12 1767 1772  782 3613  102   12 4873 2791
  1304 3683  102   12 1453 4873 2791  102   11 2512 4275 1399 4917  102
     0]
 [ 101  872 1962 8024  872 4761 6887  791 2399 5018 1724 1453 2166 2147
  6845 4495 8024 6820 3300 6929 6956 1920 7942 6044 2124  812 4873 2791
  2600 4638 1304 3683 1408  102   12 1767 1772  782 3613  102   12 4873
  2791 1304 3683  102   12 1453 4873 2791  102   11 2512 4275 1399 4917
   102]]
input_segment_ids : shape(2, 57)
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
input_header_ids : shape(2, 4)
[[33 39 45 50]
 [34 40 46 51]]
input_header_mask : shape(2, 4)
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
output_sel_agg : shape(2, 4, 1)
[[[6]
  [5]
  [6]
  [6]]

 [[6]
  [5]
  [6]
  [6]]]
output_cond_conn_op : shape(2, 1)
[[2]
 [2]]
output_cond_op : shape(2, 4, 1)
[[[4]
  [4]
  [4]
  [2]]

 [[4]
  [4]
  [4]
  [2]]]
```

And in the prediction part, he extracted the the columns embedding vectors through the ids he preprocessed, and doing multiply then sent them into the Dense layer. The Model structure  looks like this.

```
def seq_gather(x):
    seq, idxs = x
    idxs = K.cast(idxs, 'int32')
    return tf.gather_nd(seq, idxs)

bert_model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(paths.config, paths.checkpoint, seq_len=None)
for l in bert_model.layers:
    l.trainable = True
    
inp_token_ids = Input(shape=(None,), name='input_token_ids', dtype='int32')
inp_segment_ids = Input(shape=(None,), name='input_segment_ids', dtype='int32')
inp_header_ids = Input(shape=(None,), name='input_header_ids', dtype='int32')
inp_header_mask = Input(shape=(None, ), name='input_header_mask')

x = bert_model([inp_token_ids, inp_segment_ids]) # (None, seq_len, 768)

# predict cond_conn_op
x_for_cond_conn_op = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(x) # (None, 768)
p_cond_conn_op = Dense(num_cond_conn_op, activation='softmax', name='output_cond_conn_op')(x_for_cond_conn_op)

# predict sel_agg
x_for_header = Lambda(seq_gather)([x, inp_header_ids]) # (None, h_len, 768)
header_mask = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))(inp_header_mask) # (None, h_len, 1)

#x_for_header = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([x_for_header,header_mask])
#x_for_header = Masking()(x_for_header)

p_sel_agg = Dense(num_sel_agg, activation='softmax', name='output_sel_agg')(x_for_header)

x_for_cond_op = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x_for_header, p_sel_agg])

p_cond_op = Dense(num_cond_op, activation='softmax', name='output_cond_op')(x_for_cond_op)


model = Model(
    [inp_token_ids, inp_segment_ids, inp_header_ids, inp_header_mask],
    [p_cond_conn_op, p_sel_agg, p_cond_op]
)
```

But when I ran the code, it raised error which means that doing the multiply needs the specific Input Shape, and the number of columns varies in different data, when I removed that line and continued, to check if the results could be the same even without the masking, it raised another error that the last dimension to the dense layer should be defined.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b0a3d0700bdf> in <module>()
     10 #x_for_header = Masking()(x_for_header)
     11 
---> 12 p_sel_agg = Dense(num_sel_agg, activation='softmax', name='output_sel_agg')(x_for_header)
     13 
     14 x_for_cond_op = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x_for_header, p_sel_agg])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dense.py in build(self, input_shape)
    137     last_dim = tf.compat.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])
    138     if last_dim is None:
--> 139       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer '
    140                        'should be defined. Found None. '
    141                        f'Full input shape received: {input_shape}')

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: <unknown>
```

So I wonder if somewhere in the code is wrong, maybe the gather function? or just because of the version of keras since this code was pull to github in 2019. And is there some other ways to achieve this requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not include code or error messages as images, as they cannot be copied as text or searched.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited now, so please can you check whether you can help me? Thanks in advance